# Please can you check my computation of the limit of this sum of sawtooth function

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Define $h(x)=|x|$ on $[-1,1]$ and extend it to $\mathbb R$ by defining $h(2+x) = h(x)$. This is a sawtooth function that is $0$ at even and $1$ at odd integers.

Furthermore define $h_n(x) = (1/2)^n h(2^n x)$ and
$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over 2^n }h(2^n x) = \sum_{n \ge 0}h_n(x)$$

I showed that $g$ converges for all $x\in \mathbb R$. Next I am interested in computing the limit:

$$ \lim_{m \to \infty} {g(x_m) -g(0) \over x_m - 0} = \lim_{m \to \infty} {g(x_m)  \over x_m } $$ where $x_m = 2^{-m}$.

Please can you tell me if my computation is correct:

$$ {g(x_m) \over x_m} = 2^m \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n}h(2^{n-m})$$

For $n>m$ it holds that $h(2^{n-m})=0$. Therefore

$$ {g(x_m) \over x_m} = \sum_{n=0}^m 2^{m-n}h(2^{n-m}) = \sum_{n=0}^m 2^{m-n} 2^{n-m} = \sum_{n=0}^m 4^{m-n} = \sum_{n=0}^m 4^{n} = {4\over 3}({1 -{1\over 4}^{m+1}})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a simple slip in the last line. $2^{m-n}2^{n-m}$ is $1$ and not $4^{m-n}$. This yields the solution $\sum_{n=0}^m1 = m+1$.