# Sum of sawtooth function not differentiable at dyadic rational points

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

This question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703000/please-can-you-check-my-computation-of-the-limit-of-this-sum-of-sawtooth-functio).

Define $h(x)=|x|$ on $[-1,1]$ and extend it to $\mathbb R$ by defining $h(2+x) = h(x)$. This is a sawtooth function that is $0$ at even and $1$ at odd integers.

Furthermore define $h_n(x) = (1/2)^n h(2^n x)$ and
$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over 2^n }h(2^n x) = \sum_{n \ge 0}h_n(x)$$

Now I

(a) showed that $g'(1)$ does not exist and that $g'({1\over 2})$ does not exist.

(b) Showed that $g'(x)$ does not exist for any rational number of the form $x={p \over 2^k}$ where $p\in \mathbb Z$ and $k \in \mathbb N $.

Please can you check my work:

(a) Define $x_m = 1 + {1\over 2^m}$. Then 
$$\begin{aligned} 
{g(x_m) - g(1) \over x_m - 1} &= 2^m \sum_{n \ge 0} {1\over 2^n} h(2^n + 2^{n-m}) - 2^mg(1) \\
&=  2^mh(1 + 2^{-m}) + \sum_{n \ge 1} 2^{m-n} h(2^n + 2^{n-m}) - 2^mg(1) \\
&=  2^mh(2^{-m}) + \sum_{n \ge 1} 2^{m-n} h(2^n + 2^{n-m}) - 2^mg(1) \\
&= \sum_{n \ge 0} 2^{m-n} h(2^{n-m}) - 2^mg(1) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^m 2^{m-n} h(2^{n-m}) - 2^mg(1) \\
&= m + 1 - 2^m g(1) \to - \infty
\end{aligned}$$

hence $g'(1)$ does not exist. Next define $x_m = {1\over 2} + {1 \over 2^m}$. Then

$$\begin{aligned} 
{g(x_m) - g({1\over 2}) \over x_m - {1\over 2}} = {g(x_m) - g({1\over 2}) \over {1\over 2^m} - {1\over 2}}  &= {2^{m+1}\over 2-2^m} \left ( \sum_{n \ge 0} {1\over 2^n} h(2^{n-1} + 2^{n-m}) - 2^mg({1\over 2}) \right )\\
&=  {2^{m+1}\over 2-2^m} \left ( \sum_{n = 0}^m {1\over 2^n} h(2^{n-m}) - 2^mg({1\over 2}) \right )\\
&=  {2 \over 2-2^m} \left ( \sum_{n = 0}^m 2^{m-n} h(2^{n-m}) - 2^m 2^mg({1\over 2}) \right )\\
&=  {2 \over 2-2^m} \left ( m+1 - 2^{2m} g({1\over 2}) \right )\\
&\to  \infty
\end{aligned}$$

(b) Let $x = {p \over 2^k}$ and $x_m = x + {1 \over 2^m}$. Then

$$\begin{aligned} 
{g(x_m) - g(x) \over x_m -x} = {g(x_m) - g(x) \over {1\over 2^m}} &= 2^m \sum_{n \ge 0} {1\over 2^n} h(x2^n + 2^{n-m}) - 2^mg(x) \\
&= 2^m \sum_{n \ge 0} {1\over 2^n} h(2^{n-k} + 2^{n-m}) - 2^mg(x)  \\
&= 2^m \sum_{n = 0}^{m+k} {1\over 2^n} h(2^{n-k} + 2^{n-m}) - 2^mg(x)  \\
&= \left ( \sum_{n = 0}^{m+k}  2^{m-k} + 1 \right ) - 2^mg(x)  \\
&= (m+ k + 1) 2^{m-k} + (m+ k + 1)  - 2^mg(x)  \\
&\xrightarrow{m \to \infty} \infty
\end{aligned}$$
hence the derivative of $g$ does not exist at $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first part of (a) you replaced $h(1+2^{-m})$ by $h(2^{-m})$ going from second to third line. This is incorrect; the two values are not equal. I think there are similar mistakes in other parts too. In all cases, the divergence of divided differences to infinity should be of order $m$, not exponential in $m$.

I suggest writing a proof in a modular way, using some sentences along the formulas. A proof that is only a long chain of formulas is hard to read and to debug. I would write something like:

Since $h$ is $2$-periodic, the function $h_n(x) = 2^{-n}h(2^nx)$ is $2^{1-n}$-periodic. Therefore, the tail of the series $\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty h_n(x)$ is $2^{-m}$-periodic. For any $x\in\mathbb R$, the divided difference of $h(x+2^{-m})$ and $h(x)$ simplifies to
$$\frac{g(x+2^{-m})-g(x)}{2^{-m}} =  \sum_{n=0}^m 2^{m-n}\bigg(h (2^nx+2^{n-m})-h (2^nx)\bigg) \tag{1}$$
Suppose $x=p/2^k$ here, with $p$, $k$ as in the problem statement. Then for $n> k$ the number $2^nx$ is an even integer, hence $h(2^nx)=0$. Also, for  $n=k+1,\dots,  m$ we have $$h (2^nx+2^{n-m}) = h(2^{n-m}) = 2^{n-m}$$ Using the above, rewrite the right side of (1) as 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^k 2^{m-n}\bigg(h (2^nx+2^{n-m})-h (2^nx)\bigg)  +\sum_{n=k+1}^m 2^{m-n} 2^{n-m}  \tag{2}$$
The first sum is bounded by $2(k+1)\max|g|$, the second is equal to $(m-k)$ and thus  tends to infinity as $m\to\infty$.

Comment: This is excellent, and highlights something important. Words are good. Often they are more understandable than a mess of equations. Don't be afraid to write.

Also, something to think about (though if this isn't for an introductory analysis class than this will probably be obvious), does it follow that $h(x)$ is *nowhere* differentiable?

Comment: @StellaBiderman Thanks for your comment. Actually, blue was already thinking of the nowhere differentiability; the points other than dyadic rationals are [treated elsewhere](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/705331/127096). (They do require a separate proof from this one).

Comment: Excellent. The answer to my question is no, though I frequently see introductory students making the mistake of saying "since the dyadics are dense, it is nowhere differentiable". That's not true, it doesn't *follow* from this proof that that is the case.

Comment: I found a new proof and tried to prove again using less formula. Please find my new trial [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776998/sum-of-sawtooth-functions-not-differentiable-anywhere).