# Sum of sawtooth functions not differentiable at dyadic points

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Define $h(x)=|x|$ on $[-1,1]$ and extend it to $\mathbb R$ by defining $h(2+x) = h(x)$. This is a sawtooth function that is $0$ at even and $1$ at odd integers.

Furthermore define $h_n(x) = (1/2)^n h(2^n x)$ and
$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over 2^n }h(2^n x) = \sum_{n \ge 0}h_n(x)$$

Let $x={k\over 2^i}$ where $k \in \mathbb Z, i \in \mathbb N$ be a dyadic point. I tried to prove (again) that $g'(x)$ for any such $x$ does not exist. Please could someone check my proof? This time I try to use less formula and more words.

Let $x_m = x + {1\over 2^m}$. Since we are interested in the limit as $m \to \infty$ we may assume $m > i+ 1$ for the computations.

$$ \begin{align}
{g(x_m)-g(x) \over x_m - x} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{m-n}h(2^n x + 2^{n-m}) - \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{m-n}h(2^n x) \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{m-n}h(2^{n-i} k + 2^{n-m}) - \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{m-n}h(2^{n-i} k) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^i 2^{m-n}h(2^{n-i} k + 2^{n-m}) + \sum_{n=i+1}^\infty 2^{m-n}h(2^{n-i} k + 2^{n-m})- \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{m-n}h(2^{n-i} k) \\
\end{align}$$

In the middle sum, for $n > i$ it holds that $h(2^{n-i} k + 2^{n-m}) = h(2^{n-m})$ hence the middle sum equals $m - (i + 1)$:

$$ \begin{align}
{g(x_m)-g(x) \over x_m - x}
&= \sum_{n=0}^i 2^{m-n}h(2^{n-i} k + 2^{n-m}) + m-(i+1)- \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{m-n}h(2^{n-i} k) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^i 2^{m-n}\left ( h(2^{n-i} k + 2^{n-m})-h(2^{n-i} k) \right )+ m-(i+1) \\
\end{align}$$

Since $h$ is piecewise linear with slope $1$:

$$ -2^{n-m} \le h(2^{n-i} k + 2^{n-m})-h(2^{n-i} k)  \le 2^{n-m}$$

Hence

$$ \begin{align}
{g(x_m)-g(x) \over x_m - x}
&= \sum_{n=0}^i 2^{m-n}\left ( h(2^{n-i} k + 2^{n-m})-h(2^{n-i} k) \right )+ m-(i+1) \\
&\ge -\sum_{n=0}^i 1 + m - (i+1) \\
&= -2(i+1) + m
\end{align}$$

Hence

$$ g'(x) = \lim_{m \to \infty }{g(x_m)-g(x) \over x_m - x} = \infty$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof is correct. The only thing would be nice to add in your proof is to explain in more detail why the middle sum is $m-(i+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

$$ \begin{align}
{g(x_m)-g(x) \over x_m - x}
&= \sum_{n=0}^i 2^{m-n}h(2^{n-i} k + 2^{n-m}) + m-(i+1)- \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{m-n}h(2^{n-i} k) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^i 2^{m-n}\left ( h(2^{n-i} k + 2^{n-m})-h(2^{n-i} k) \right )+ m-(i+1) \\
\end{align}$$

A term is missing here. What happened to

$$\sum_{n={i+1}}^\infty 2^{m-n}h(2^{n-i} k)$$

You must also mention that it's bounded too, then it's OK.

Comment: For $n \ge i + 1$ the $h(2^{n-i}k)$ is $0$.